# Form of Energy in Compressed Gas

Tags: potential-energy, gas

What would be the best way to categorize the energy stored in a compressed gas?

Should I call elastic potential energy?  Maybe mechanical?

It's not that exotic a way to store energy but it doesn't seem to fit neatly into any of the textbook lists of forms of energy.

Comment: Kinetic energy, the compressed gas molecules have a higher incidence of collisions with each other and the container walls.

Comment: pressure has units of energy per volume

Comment: My comment assumed you meant the potential energy of the compressed gas and its ability to do work with pneumatic tools as pressure is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal energy $U$ of a  given mass  of  an *ideal* gas  depends only its temperature. It is the *same* whether the gas is compressed or not.  What the compressed gas has is more of is  *free energy*. This is  defined as $F=U-TS$ where $T$ is the temperature and $S$ is the entropy
$$
S= NR(\ln V + constant).
$$
Here $N$ is the number of moles of gas present and $R=8.31$ J K$^{-1}$ mol$^{-1}$ is the gas constant. The enrotropy of the compressed gas is smaller by $NR\ln( V_{smaller}/V_{original})$  and so the compressed gas has more free energy than the uncompressed. It is the free energy that is available to do work, and is the approprite  analogue of the energy stored in a spring.

So the anwer to your question is that the best characterization of the stored energy is that it is  *entropic*.

Comment: Fascinating.  Thanks